# Did the GOT scriptwriter change in Season 5?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I have been watching *Game of Thrones* season 5 and the dialogue seems to have a much different style than previous seasons, and the action is much slower paced. It is like these long sequences of conversations instead of anything real happening.

Did the screenwriter, the story line creator or some other factor change? What happened?

Comment: You do know that these big shows have multiple writers working as a team right?

Comment: If you care about this, why not read the credits? There's IMDb, Wikipedia,...

Comment: This question should be rephrased to "did GOT change their approach to story telling,  and it's there any confirmation by staff for that?". For example, the reimagined Battlestar Galactica changed their approach by cutting back on the space battles, and increasing the soap dialog, to draw in a female 25-40 crowd, and they admitted it in interviews.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Have you tried looking up the writing credits on IMDB and Wikipedia? It's surprisingly hard. Both credit only the showrunners, plus "Dave Hill, who was promoted to staff writer this season after previously working as an assistant to Benioff and Weiss". It's not clear if this is the entire writing team (unlikely) or if there are also uncredited assistants.

Comment: @user568458 http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Writer and http://www.westeros.org/GoT/News/Entry/HBO_Releases_Season_3_Episode_Writers_and_Directors etc. But in the end this question doesn't provide any facts, merely impressions.

Answer (score 8):

I can only see evidence of three changes to the writing team (though I'm having trouble finding any detail on who exactly does what within the writing team):

- Reduced involvement of George RR Martin in Season 5 (he's the author of the books the show is based on), who wrote one episode every season before Season 5, when he was working full time (we hope!) on trying to finish the next novel, The Winds of Winter.
- [The promotion of *"Dave Hill,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones_(season_5)#Crew) who was promoted to staff writer this season after previously working as an assistant to Benioff and Weiss". Maybe as first-time "Staff Writer" he was allowed to write the Dorne storyline unsupervised, which might explain a lot... This is just speculation unfortunately, I can't find much information on how the actual writing duties are divided.
- [Brian Cogman](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2643685/)'s role  changing from "**Co-producer**" (Seasons 1-4) to "**Producer**" (Season 5, then "Supervising producer" in Season 6 and "Co-executive producer" in Season 7). (Thanks for the comment [Möoz](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/11244/m%c3%b6oz))

---

There is one objective change however - **all the episodes except episodes 9 and 10 had directors who hadn't worked on the show before.**

### The "slower pace" episodes' directors

These directors had mostly worked on less action-oriented shows:

- 1 and 2 by [Micheal Slovis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Slovis) who had previously worked on various crime dramas including CSI and Law and Order
- 3 and 4 by [Mark Mylod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Mylod) who had worked mainly on comedies and the acclaimed British relationship-drama Cold Feet
- 5 and 6 by [Jeremy Podeswa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Podeswa) who had worked on many "dark" dramas such as Six Feet Under and Boardwalk Empire

### The "faster pace" episodes' directors

- 7 and 8 by [Miguel Sapochnik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_Sapochnik) who was a storyboard artist for the film Trainspotting and a director for a few varied shows including House
- 9 and 10 by [David Nutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Nutter), the only one to have worked on Game of Thrones before, in seasons 2 and 3 (including "The Rains of Castermere").

Comment: The other change worth noting is [Bryan Cogman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2643685/) went from executive story writer to supervising producer (almost same level as D&D)

Answer (score -9):

That's not actually possible. Each episode of GOT has been and is being done based on the books R.R Martin writes. The GOT guys, like have the copyright to the books' content. As long as the old Martin is alive, that won't be happening.

Comment: Um, those episodes are still written by actual screenwriters you know. Even if G. R. R. Martin gives the rough story development, you still need someone to actually write a screenplay, which GRRM usually doesn't do. Especially since the show deviates further and further from the source novels in later seasons.

Comment: Adaptation differences are really large. People complain all the time about it. Scenes in the book are changed and some are omitted, some are created. Even then, dialog is added or changed as needed for screen which is different from a box. We don't hear minds on tv, while books are omnipresent